# Materialize.toast in angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize

I am working on angular 2. I have used materialize-css which works fine with classes But problem came with `materialize toast`.  I Configured materialize with gulpfile.js do i need to add any other js file in gulpfile?

`<a class="btn" (click)="Materialize.toast('I am a toast', 4000)">Toast!</a>`

Used this console shows error
`Materialize is not defined`

Comment: Could you provide how you configure materialize in your HTML file (JS file included and SystemJS configuration)? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.   Wish I knew why - I could not find this documented anywhere.

```
import { toast } from 'angular2-materialize';

ngOnInit() {
   toast("I am the best toast there is!", 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Materialize CSS correctly for your project.  I'm using [Angular 2 Materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize)  myself.

Comment: i had configured through gulpfile.. The css of materialize works properly in my project.. Problem only came for toast

Comment: how to install and configure webpack?

Answer (score 0):

your component.ts

```
import { toast } from 'angular2-materialize';

ngOnInit() {}

miToast() {
    toast("I am the best toast there is!", 4000);
}
```

Your componen.html

```
<a class="btn" (click)="miToast()">Toast!</a>
```

or you can also use

Your component.ts

```
// imports...

declare var Materialize: any;

ngOnInit() {}

miToast(){
    Materialize.toast("I am the best toast there is!", 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like is too late but for the people comming from the future

This is how is imported

```
import {Toast} from 'materialize-css';
```

then on the template

```
<a class="btn" (click)="toast()">Toast!</a>
```

and finally on the typescript file for the component

```
toast() {
// to avoid lint warnings
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
new Toast({
  html: 'I am a toast',
  classes: 'rounded',
  displayLength: 4000
});
```

}

thats all